# How can I write exponents in a PySide QLabel?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I'm writing a Qt interface for a computing program and I would like to write in the units for an area (ie, the LaTex output of `m^2`, or m².)

If I use the special ² character in this code: `area_label = QtGui.QLabel("m²")`, it will display the following in the GUI: `mÂ²`.

I suspect this could be an encoding issue, what would be the way to write the squared exponent I'm looking for?

Additional question: is there a way to output *any* exponent, any one not defined as a special character (say `m^8`)?

Additional info:
I'm working on python 2.7.2, with PySide version 1.1.1, and Qt 4.7.4. Working in Windows 7, SP1, but I would like my code to be cross-platform if possible.

Also, as I'm working on windows and I use french accents (like `à` and `é`), I'm using this encoding line at the beginning of my file: `# -*-coding:Latin-1 -*`.

Comment: You'll have to show us some sample code, and tell us whether you're using Python 2.x or 3.x, if you want us to help figure out your encoding issues.

Comment: However… `mÂ²` is exactly what you get if you encode `m²` as UTF-8 and then try to display the result as Latin-1, so… one possibility is that you're encoding to UTF-8, but you've got Qt configured for your system default, which is something like cp1252. (IIRC, `PySide` can take decoded `unicode` strings as well as `str`/`bytes` strings just about everywhere; if so, the easy solution is to just use unicode everywhere.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your encoding problem appears to be that you're passing UTF-8 strings, which PySide/Qt is trying to interpret according to your system encoding, which is something Latin-1 compatible (like cp1252, the traditional Windows default for western European languages) rather than UTF-8. You can see this pretty easily:

```
>>> print u'm\u00b2'.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')
mÂ²
```

PySide can take `unicode` strings everywhere. So, if you just use `unicode` everywhere instead of `str`/`bytes`, including at the interface to PySide, you should be fine.

---

> is there a way to output any exponent, any one not defined as a special character (say m^8)?

Well, ⁸ (U+2078) *is* defined as a special character, as evidenced by the fact that I was able to type it here.

However, you will have to write your own code to parse your expressions and generate proper superscript characters.

The superscripts and subscripts block in U+2070 to U+209F has all of the characters you need, except for 2 and 3, which were left in their Latin-1-compatible positions at U+00B2 and U+00B3. (Some fonts will display U+2072 and U+2073 as equivalent characters, but those fonts are not correct, so you shouldn't depend on that. Also, 1 appears as both U+2071 and U+00B9, and some fonts distinguish them. You may want to print out the whole list and see which ones look better for you.)

The function to turn each digit into a superscript looks like this:

```
def superscript(digit):
    if digit in (2, 3):
        return unichr(0x00B0 + digit)
    else:
        return unichr(0x2070 + digit)
```

So, a really simple wrapper would be:

```
def term(base, exponent):
    return base + u''.join(superscript(int(digit)) for digit in exponent)
```

Now:

```
>>> print term('x', '123')
xⁱ²³
```

---

However, if you want something more flexible, you're probably going to want to generate HTML instead of plain text. Recent versions of Qt can take HTML directly in a `QLabel`.

If you can generate MathML, Latex, etc. from your expressions, there are tools that generate HTML from those formats.

But for a really trivial example:

```
def term(base, exponent):
    return u'{}<sup>{}</sup>'.format(base, exponent)
```

When printed out, this will just show `x<sup>123</sup>`, but when stuck in a `QLabel` (or a Stack Overflow answer), that shows as x<sup>123</sup>.

---

> I'm usint this encoding line: `# -*-coding:Latin-1 -*`.

Why? If it's at all possible for you to edit text files in UTF-8, that will make your life a lot easier. For one thing, Latin-1 doesn't have characters for any superscripts but 1, 2, and 3, which means you will have to write things like `u'm\2074'` instead of just writing `u'm⁴'`

Also, it's a bit misleading to use a coding declaration which is almost, but not quite, in emacs format. Either use emacs format (with the final hyphen and proper spacing):

```
# -*- coding: Latin-1 -*-
```

… or don't:

```
# coding=Latin-1
```

At any rate, all the encoding line does is to tell Python how to interpret your string literals. If you create non-`unicode` literals (without the `u` prefix), you still have to `decode` them at some point. And, if you don't do that decoding yourself, PySide will have to guess, and it will guess your system encoding (which is probably cp1252—which is close enough to Latin-1 for superscripts, but not close enough to UTF-8).

So, to solve all of your problems:

- Use UTF-8 encoding if possible.
- If you can't use UTF-8 encoding, use explicit Unicode escapes or dynamic generation of strings to handle the characters Latin-1 is missing in your literals.
- Make all of your literals Unicode.
- Use Unicode strings wherever possible in your code.
- If you do need byte strings anywhere, explicitly encode/decode them rather than letting Python/PySide/Qt guess for you.

Comment: Thanks, with your hints, I was able to find a solution. I needed to change my first line to `# -*-coding:UTF-8 -*` to make it accept non-ascii characters, AND I have to change my string from `"spam²"` to `u"spam²"` to make it work. I still have no idea why I have to do it this way.

Comment: @PhilMacKay: You need the coding declaration if you want to use any Unicode characters in iterals, because otherwise Python interprets those literals as Latin-1. You need the `u` prefix because otherwise those literals are encoded UTF-8 byte strings, not Unicode strings—and, as I explained, if you pass encoded byte strings to PySide, it will try to decode them using your system encoding, which is not UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept your answer because you helped me understand the situation and solve it.